# How to make a macro that calculates time based on different inputs

Tags: plc

I am creating a PLC program for a self-service car wash and I have encountered a problem that I am not able to get over.
The scenario is the following:

The person that comes to wash his/her car is able to select up from 8 programs (6 having 90 seconds time, and other 2 having 60 seconds) - but for simplicity let's just assume we are talking about 3 programs (2 having 60 seconds time and the other having 90 seconds.

When the user presses the first button (60 seconds program), the timer should start and open the first output. If he presses again the same button, nothing should happen and the timer will stop when 60 seconds pass.
If the user chooses another 60 seconds program, the set-time for the seconds program should be 60 seconds (full program) - x (where X is the seconds that passes since he pressed the first button).
If he chooses a 60 seconds program, then presses on 90 seconds program, he should be given x (time passed since he pressed first button) / 60 (procent of the first program) * 90 seconds.

I am having some problems writing this MACRO since I can't actually save the state of the last pressed buttons and not having if/else conditions (I have tried MUXes)

This is the scenario I have developed so far:

[image]

Do you guys have any inputs on how I should change it to make it work as expected?

I also think it's worth mentioning that I am using a ZelioSoft 2 as IDE and the PLC is SR3B261BD from Schneider

Thank you for the time reading my question!